# R CMD REMOVE has no effect

Tags: r, package

```
$ /usr/bin/R --vanilla CMD REMOVE xgboost
Removing from library ‘/home/arferk01/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
```

But the directory's still there:

```
$ ls /home/arferk01/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/xgboost
data  DESCRIPTION  html   libs     Meta       R
demo  help         INDEX  LICENSE  NAMESPACE
```

Likewise if I say `/usr/bin/R --vanilla -e 'remove.packages("xgboost")'`.

What's going on?

I'm running R 3.5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out: it was a permissions issue. I'd installed a package to my user library with root ownership because I'd forgotten the `-H` in `sudo R CMD INSTALL`. What's inscrutable is that `CMD REMOVE` gives no error message.